# Counting holes in a mesh

Tags: python, geometry, triangulation, triangular

I have a special kind of triangular mesh. (i.e. I haven't used a regular algorithm to triangulate the set of points I have, but I followed a special algorithm to do this for chemical data). The result is a complicated 3D shape consits of a lot of triangles and tetrahesrons.

Before I can proceed my task, I need to count the number of holes in the surfaces (holes between the triangles) and the 'Voids' (Empty volumes) between the tetrahedrons.

Example of holes in a simple shape from my data:

[image]

[image]

Is there any known algorithm to achieve this or any python library that helps in doing this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the quantities you are trying to compute are the first and second [Betti numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number) of a simplicial complex. If you do a google search, you will find some literature on various ways to compute such things. A lot of them seem to be matrix-based (see e.g. https://jeremykun.com/2013/04/10/computing-homology/). There is also a direct way to do it for your problem based on collapsing edges. I'll see if I can write a quick implementation of it (I'm not sure if it will be simpler than the matrices).